# Extract multiple first names, surnames and middle names from one cell

Tags: excel, vba, string, split, slice

I have a string of text in cells O9:O75 formatted as
surname, first name middle names : surname, first name middle names : surname, first name middle names : etc

For example
MOLIJN, SEBASTIAAN : GOTTWALD, LUKASZ : MARAJ, ONIKA TANYA : OGREN, RYAN : VALDES, ROCCO : Petras, Kim : Kalberg, Eelke

I need..
first name middle names;first name middle names;first name middle names;first name middle names;etc
In cells X9:X75

As well as
surname;surname;surname;surname;etc
In cells Y9:Y75

The string of text may have 1 name, to any number of names, up to around 20.

Many thanks in advance

I’ve tried using VBA left right and mid string functions with no success.

Comment: Use [`Split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/split-function) twice: first on `:` and then on `,`

Answer (score 2):

This is basically a little bit string handling and the function [`Split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/split-function) is the key. You just need to know that it returns an 0-indexed array of strings.

So first split the string by `":"` to get a list of all persons. Now loop over the persons and split that name by `","` to separate surname from first (and optional middle) name.

Glue those names together using the separator character of your choice.

The following function can be used as UDF:

```
Function getNames(S As String, getSurnames As Boolean) As String
    Const NameSeparator = ":"
    Const SurnameSeparator = ","
    Const ResultSeparator = ";"
    
    Dim allPersons() As String
    ' First we create an array with one entry per person
    allPersons = Split(S, NameSeparator)
    
    ' Decide if we want to have first or second piece of the name
    Dim namePartIndex As Long
    namePartIndex = IIf(getSurnames, 0, 1)
    
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 0 To UBound(allPersons)
        ' Split the name of a person.
        Dim nameparts() As String
        nameparts() = Split(allPersons(i), SurnameSeparator)
        If UBound(nameparts) >= namePartIndex Then
            getNames = getNames & IIf(getNames = "", "", ResultSeparator) & Trim(nameparts(namePartIndex))
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Now all you have to do is to put formulas into columns X and Y:

```
=getNames(O5, getSurnames:=False)  ' For Firstnames (and Middle Names)
=getNames(O5, getSurnames:=True)   ' For Surnames
```

**Update:** Sorry for the confusion, Named parameters are not allowed when calling a function from Excel. This should be

```
=getNames(O5, False)  ' For Firstnames (and Middle Names)
=getNames(O5, True)   ' For Surnames
```

Comment: Thank you so much for replying, unfortunately I cannot get it to work, when entering the formulas suggested it returns an error and places the cursor just after “=getNames(O5, getSurnames:” any further advice greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, did a mistake when copying my test into the function. See my update.